# Connecting Spring boot application to Oracle database 12.2.0.1 in Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, oracle12c, flyway, connection-timeout

I have Oracle database running as Docker container and following are the container details.

```
Config: {
        "Hostname": "8ad016675bd2",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "oracle",
        "AttachStdin": true,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "1521/tcp": {},
            "5500/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "StdinOnce": true,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1",
            "ORACLE_SID=ORCL"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "/bin/bash /home/oracle/setup/dockerInit.sh"
        ],
        "Healthcheck": {
            "Test": [
                "CMD-SHELL",
                "/bin/bash /home/oracle/setup/healthcheck.sh"
            ],
            "Interval": 60000000000,
            "Timeout": 10000000000
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "c13a0ee218e9245d7916c7ffb078adf4191a14e100221274f3125975fc6cb5b7",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "1521/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "32773"
                }
            ],
            "5500/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "32772"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/c13a0ee218e9",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "782fa0c989db7f58643416fea7b60165ad00ce3067b7bb7a6af72c0619c31e5a",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "486e58b051b36eb20838e5f9edcb6fe205407e583e75fedf86460ecec41dd9c5",
                "EndpointID": "782fa0c989db7f58643416fea7b60165ad00ce3067b7bb7a6af72c0619c31e5a",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
```

I am trying to connect to the oracle database with Flyway using below credentials

```
spring.jpa.database=oracle
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.0.2:32773/ORCLPDB1
spring.datasource.username=sys
spring.datasource.password=Oradoc_db1
```

But I am getting following error

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:523) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:521) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:660) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:286) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out: connect, socket connect lapse 21030 ms. /172.17.0.2 32773 30000 1 true
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:161) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
... 40 common frames omitted

Unable to obtain connection from database: IO Error: The Network Adapter 
could not establish the connection
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------------------------------
SQL State  : 08006
Error Code : 17002
Message    : IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the 
connection
```

Can anybody point out what I am missing here? And how to fix this.

Comment: I guess oracle is exposed from the container in 1521 and you are trying to connect with 32773. Please confirm if the port exposed by the oracle in 32773?

Comment: @BalajiSrinivasan Port number seems to be fine. Running `docker port` command gives `1521/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32773
5500/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32772`

Comment: Are you able to connect to the oracle via any SQL clients ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the correct port exposed by the container for 1521/tcp port:

```
docker port your_containerID 1521/tcp
```

Then make sure  that your database in the container is up:
`docker ps` (* check while the container status is not healthy)

1.- Connect with sqlplus

```
docker exec -it your_containerID bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"
```

2.- Connect with jdbc using for example SQL Developer IDE and create a scheme:

```
create user "MYUSER" identified by  admin123 default tablespace "USERS" temporary tablespace "TEMP";
grant "DBA" to "MYUSER";
grant "RESOURCE" to "MYUSER";

grant SELECT ANY DICTIONARY to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE SEQUENCE to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE SYNONYM to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE SESSION to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE TYPE to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE PROCEDURE to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE DATABASE LINK to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE ANY DIRECTORY to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE TABLE to "MYUSER";
grant EXPORT FULL DATABASE to "MYUSER";
grant UNLIMITED TABLESPACE to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE JOB to "MYUSER";
grant CREATE VIEW to "MYUSER";
grant ALTER SESSION to "MYUSER";

grant EXECUTE on "SYS"."SYS_PLSQL_FAA5F685_2385_1" to "MYUSER";
grant EXECUTE on "SYS"."SYS_PLSQL_D9B1149D_9_1" to "MYUSER";
```

And the last step in you application.yml:

```
datasource:
    username: MYUSER
    password: admin123
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=your_docker_ip)(protocol=tcp)(port=your_port_number))(connect_data=(service_name=ORCLPDB1.localdomain)))
```